# External script src and $.ready() inside ajax response

Tags: jquery, ajax, requirejs

Our page is made up of a main view file, and then several 'elements' (reusable pieces, such as bootstrap-modals which get injected into the view when rendering). Some of the elements contain script tags to grab external js required for their particular functionality, ie:

```
<script src="//some.external.cdn/lib.min.js">
```

The element code will then apply it's own functionality via:

```
<script>
     $.ready(function(){
       // attach some element-specific listeners.
     });
</script>
```

This was all working fine until we decided to move the element into a page loaded via AJAX. The scripts get executed, however the required library files no longer block the execution of the $.ready(function(){}); within the element. It seems that those dependencies are now loaded asynchronously.

I realise we can move the `<script src="//....">` tag into the base page, so it is loaded prior to performing any Ajax, however this makes the element less 'pluggable' because whichever page includes it needs to be aware that it also needs to include that script tag in it's own header.

What are the best methods of dealing with this? I've researched using RequireJS to handle loading the additional dependencies within the element itself (as I believe this could re-enable the 'blocking' nature), but wasn't sure if this was overkill.

Answer (score 0):

Ok from what you have said, it appears your AJAX loaded content depend on external scripts, and the only way to properly handle this kind of scenario is via a dependency manager like requireJS, yepnope, head.JS, etc. Another thing you can do is to use jQuery's `$.getScript()` function to asynchronously load the external scripts and then place the code that depends on that script in the callback since jQuery knows to call the callback function after the script has been loaded and executed.

Answer (score 0):

When building sites with reusable components, I usually handle this the other way around; instead of HTML chunks bringing in their scripts, have the scripts bring in their HTML.

As a basic example in require.js you could do something like:

*mainView.html*

```
<div id="headerRegion"></div>

<script src="require.js" data-main="mainView.js"></script>
```

*mainView.js*

```
require(['headerWidget'], function (HeaderWidget) {
    var headerElement = $('#headerRegion');
    var header = new HeaderWidget(headerElement);
});
```

*headerWidget.html*

```
<header><h1>Wow!</h1></header>
```

*headerWidget.js*

```
define(['text!headerWidget.html'], function (headerTemplate) {
    return function (element) {
        $(headerTemplate.appendTo(element);
    };
});
```

Note that this uses the require.js text plugin to load the HTML file as a string into the javascript function.

This of course isn't the only way to do it, but its the way I usually like to do it. The r.js optimizer would handle pulling in the html file into the optimized .js file too, or could load it at runtime if not run through the r.js optimizer.